# How to get a substring pandas series using slice() while there is no pattern to determine the stop argument

Tags: python, pandas, slice, series

From this pandas series :

```
Full_Name :

Braund, Mr. Owen Harris   
Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...   
Heikkinen, Miss. Laina    
Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)    
Allen, Mr. William Henry
```

How to get this series:

```
Last_Name :

Braund 
Cumings   
Heikkinen    
Futrelle    
Allen
```

I thought this code might work but it didnt, it returns a NaN column:

```
last_name = df['Name'].str.slice(start=0,stop= col.str.find(','))
```

Comment: Something like `[sub.split(', ')[0] for sub in series.tolist()]`, but you should post `series.to_dict()` first to make it easier for people to reproduce your series

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using a list comprehension because `StringMethods` are usually very slow

```
%timeit df.Name.str.split(', ').str[0]
1.09 ms ± 142 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit [k.split(', ')[0] for k in df.Name.tolist()]
178 µs ± 2.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit pd.Series([k.split(', ')[0] for k in df.Name.tolist()])
285 µs ± 618 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

Setup:

```
z = io.StringIO("""Name
Braund, Mr. Owen Harris   
Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...   
Heikkinen, Miss. Laina    
Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)    
Allen, Mr. William Henry """)

df = pd.read_table(z)
df = pd.concat([df]*100).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Yo be fair, your should time `pd.Series([k.split(', ')[0] for k in df.Name.tolist()])`, because the output is supposed to be a Series.

Comment: Not sure this is necessarily true, but ok I'll add the timing. It is still gonna be way faster

Comment: Surely the question "How to get this series" means the OP wants a series.

Answer (score 1):

Split the names by commas and take the first part of each split:

```
last_name = df['name'].str.split(',').str[0]
#0       Braund
#1      Cumings
#2    Heikkinen
#3     Futrelle
#4        Allen
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `extract`

```
df.Name.str.extract(r'^(.+?),',expand=True)
Out[149]: 
           0
0     Braund
1    Cumings
2  Heikkinen
3   Futrelle
4      Allen
```